# For Loop Using Rows of Zipped List Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, zip

I have two lists that have both contain a mixture of strings and integers. The lists are formatted as follows:

```
list1 = L1, [-76.500000, -67.500000, 40.750000, 47.750000], [915,922,932,906]
list2 = L2, [-72.500000, -67.500000, 42.680000, 46.000000], [912,882,851,856]
```

I've merged these lists into a new list. My initial approach was to use zip in the following fashion:

```
zip(list1,list2)
```

To interrogate the final list to see its contents, I wrote the following:

```
for x, y in zip(list1,list2)):
    print(x, y)
```

The result is as follows:

```
L1 L2
[-76.5, -67.5, 40.75, 47.75] [-72.5, -67.5, 42.68, 46.0]
[915, 922, 932, 906] [912, 882, 851, 856]
```

I would like to construct the for loop in the line of code above such that each entry of the row is printed out within the loop like so:

**Desired Result:** `L1 [-76.5, -67.5, 40.75, 47.75] [915, 922, 932, 906]`

Any ideas on how to either reconstruct the for loop and/or the process to zip these lists so I can obtain the desired result? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the zip()? If this is not required do smt like

```
data = list1,list2     

for i in range(len(data)):
         print data[i]
```